# How to move div from left to right hand side of the screen on scroll in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to move a div from left to right slowly as the user scrolls down. It should stay within it's section and doesn't have to move back to the left when you scroll up.

I am wondering how to do this without using any external package. This is what I have so far but the circle ends up scrolling off the page and I need it to stay on the right hand side once it has gotten there.

```
<div className="App">
      <div className="sectionOne">
        <div className="circle styles" style={{ position: 'absolute', left: `${position}rem` }}></div>
      </div>
      <div className="sectionTwo"></div>
    </div>
```

```
const [position, setPosition] = useState('70')

function moveCircle() {
    const speed = 5
    const scrolltop = window.pageYOffset
    const scrollAndSpeed = scrolltop / speed

    console.log(scrollAndSpeed.toString())
    setPosition(scrollAndSpeed.toString())
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener(
      'scroll',
      function () {
        requestAnimationFrame(moveCircle)
      },
      false
    )
  }, [])
```

Comment: You could use a `Math.min( scrollAndSpeed, pageWidth)` but you need to calculate the page width yourself

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli How would using this stop it from going off to the right? I have calculated page width by using window.innerwidth

Comment: because if `scrollAndSpeed` exceeds the `pageWidth` it would use the `pageWidth` instead of the `scrollAndSpeed`. So you are setting a max value that can be reached for your `position`. It cannot go over that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed that you are using `rem` for the positioning.

So the `Math.min` would not work for this scenario. You can use the css [`clamp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp()) function.

```
style={{ position: 'absolute', left: `clamp(0vw, ${position}rem, 100vw - 1rem)` }}
```

Note that the `1rem` i have put in there, should be the width of the `.circle` element.